# How to add two columns in different dataset (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services

how to add two columns in table. What's the right expression in this case.
Be informed that I have two dataset (Extra Deduction, Checklist), these two dataset has numeric column value, how to add these two columns with different dataset.

these steps I did (may it help):-

- Open Visual Studio - New Project - in Business Intelligence section I chose Reporting Service.
- Then right click on Reports folder then I chose "Add new report".
- Then in Report Wizard I set Data Source name "DataSource1" and chose "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch" connection type.
- In Query Builder I put the XML query to bring the data that I want, it's contains two columns (Reference Number, Deduction value), dataset name is (DedctionDS).
- Then I added one more columns in the table to get another value from another dataset.
- Then I made the second dataset called (ChkListDS) with XML query to bring two columns (Reference Number, Checklist value).
- In the new column in table, I made an expression to bring the value from other dataset, the expression is ( =Lookup(Fields!DedctionRefNo.Value, Fields!ChkListRefNo.Value, Fields!ChecklistValue.Value, "ChkListDS") ).

Until now the data are perfect, but I need now to make Summation between (Deduction value) and (Checklist value), which they're in different dataset .

Please see the below picture to know what i'm trying to do .

[image: 1]

I hope I explained it very well .

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks ..

Comment: You really need to explain this in more detail. Start by explaining how are the concepts you are talking about (datasets?) interconnected. And check if this is the real name for tem. Another idea would be to embed the picture into the question - avoid providing the link for such a thing.

Comment: Mr. OzrenTkalcecKrznaric, i'm using Visual Studio 2012 to create SSRS report (Business Intelligence), and I created 2 datasets in my project, then I insert a table to view the data as you saw in the picture, I just need to know the expression to add column 1 with column 2 in different dataset. I hope I explained well what you need to know. And I got your idea. Thanks ...

Comment: I will try once more: you really have to explain exactly what you did. You skipped adding the report (how did you do it?). Another thing is exactly how did you connect the table to the data source? If you explained that, you would at least partially answer the question to yourelf: there can be only one data set for the table. And at last, to improve your own question - edit it, don't just add comments to it.

Comment: I edited the post, please see the new information as you kindly asked. And about the picture link I need at least 10 reputation to allow me to put an image without a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were the same source of data (preferably SQL Server), I would advise you to use SQL join to create one dataset. However, it seems that there is a problem with that, so you have to user another strategy.

What I have seen in another project (not my code) is that you can use one datasource as the main one, and for each row of that datasource look for the matching rows in another one. This requires Lookup() function in SSRS, and you have obviously found that it is the way to correlate two datasets.

Only thing you have to do now is to get the number from the value you have received using the lookup function and add it to the column of your choice.

Your starting expression is:

```
= Lookup(
    Fields!DedctionRefNo.Value, 
    Fields!ChkListRefNo.Value, 
    Fields!ChecklistValue.Value, 
    "ChkListDS")
```

To convert it to the decimal representation (I hope that is what you have in the database as source), you need CDec() function:

```
= CDec(Lookup(
    Fields!DedctionRefNo.Value, 
    Fields!ChkListRefNo.Value, 
    Fields!ChecklistValue.Value, 
    "ChkListDS"))
```

And at last, you want to add it with your first value, like:

```
= CDec(Lookup(
    Fields!DedctionRefNo.Value, 
    Fields!ChkListRefNo.Value, 
    Fields!ChecklistValue.Value, 
    "ChkListDS")) 
    + Fields!{Your-deduction-value-field-name}
```

And if your-deduction-value-field in the database is not decimal, you have to cast it to decimal as well, using the same CDec() function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I got an #Error says : **Warning 1 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox38.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from string "ر.س.‏24,500.00" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.** Be Informed that "ر.س." means "SAR" it's a currency.     Best Regards

Comment: Mr. OzrenTkalcecKrznaric, Your answer is perfect, and I can't connect to the database directly because i'm using MS CRM online, and about the error I think it's because the currency format. I will try to find any solution to fix it. Any way, thanks a lot I appreciate it.

Comment: Your problem is that you are receiving data in the display format, instead of receiving original numeric data that can be manipulated using ordinary arithmetic operations. If you can somehow get numeric instead formatted data (how it should be), it would work. This way you have to first parse the string and then convert it to numeric, and THEN perform addition. And this is really ugly way to do it, but it may be your only choice.